# ASP.Net: Problem with calling sequence of Text Change event of Text Box

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, textbox, textchanged

I have placed a list box and a text box with Selected Index Changed and Text Changed event respectively in an aspx page. Now If I write something in text box and then with out clicking elsewhere select a value in list box, then first Text Changed event of text box is called then selected Index Change event of list box is called. After that **again Text Change event of text box is called**. Can any body give some insight why this happening??

Below is the markup:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox_IndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="abc" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="def" />
</asp:ListBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="Text_Changed" />
```

Code behind:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {               
        protected void ListBox_IndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Text_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? I tried running this exact code and the ListBox_IndexChanged event fires first, followed by the Text_Changed event (and only once).

Comment: Ah, I see. When I test it in IE instead of Chrome, the sequence happens as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem/issue is that `AutoPostBack` works by attaching JavaScript events to your controls. Each browser handles JavaScript a little bit differently, so there's no real guarantee to the ordering.

When I try your code in **Google Chrome**, for example, the following sequence of events occurs:

1. Request sent to server

   1. ListBox_IndexChanged event gets called
   2. Text_Changed event gets called
2. Response goes back to client

However, in **Internet Explorer 8**, I noticed the following sequence:

1. Request sent to server

   1. Text_Changed event gets called
2. Response goes back to client
3. *Another* request sent to server

   1. ListBox_IndexChanged event gets called
   2. Text_Changed event gets called
4. 2nd Response goes back to client

This isn't a fault of ASP.NET, but just of varying JavaScript implementations across browsers, I suppose.

If you need to rely on a specific sequence of events, `AutoPostBack` isn't going to cut it. Depending on your situation, I might look at implementing my own JavaScript events using a cross-browser compliant library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). You could programmatically call back to the server by using the `__doPostBack()` function.

Answer (score 0):

When a new item is selected the text in the text part of the listbox is replaced with the text of the item. That's why you get the second TextChanged event.

Comment: If he wrote the code exactly as it is, there is no reason for the value to be copied to the text, therefore, I see your approach as not logical, If it is, please explain why.